# Workflow Email Reminder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, reminder

I've create workflow reminder with sharepoint 2010 workflow. the picture below.
[image]

[image]

the reminder consist of 3 steps, workflow initialization, Email Reminder Wika to Aurecon and Email Reminder Aurecon to Wika. the concept is if file created by Wika then the Email reminder Wika to aurecon is running and if file created by Aurecon then the email reminder Aurecon to Wika is running.

i've test created file by Wika and running well (Email Reminder Wika to Aurecon). but if file created by Aurecon the step is (Email Reminder Wika to Aurecon) should be (Email Reminder Aurecon to Wika). 
[image]

what should i do to fix that? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
If Current Item:Status equals IFC
  Email Wika Kijing; Aurecon Kijing; portdevco ppi
  then Stop the workflow and log done
```

If this condition from stage "Email Reminder Wika To Aurecon" evaluates to **True** then WF will end right then and there and will not go to next stage. I think this condition should be checked only in last stage as Email reminder is for the same recipients.

For workflow to get to `If created by Aurecon Kijing` in stage "Email Reminder Aurecon to Wika" the condition mentioned above must not evaluate to **True**

Just check for `If Current Item:Status equals IFC` in last stage. Hope it helps!